# Determining pinout on this Seven Segment Display

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I have a seven segment display with 14 pins on each side and three digits.  The display include a decimal point.  However, I'm struggling to figure out the function of each pin.  This item is described as a "3-digit Common-Cathode Display".
[image]

I'm struggling to find the purpose of each pin.  28/3 is not an even number, so I assume all the pins......share the cathode.  However, each segment has 8 L.E.D.s on it, so I don't know why I would has 4 extra pins or how to determine which ones are shared.

Can anyone help me with this?  Also, not sure how to check what kind of voltage/resistors it needs, I can't find a data sheet.  It's old.

Comment: how about checking with a multimeter in diode test mode?

Comment: Here are a pair of datasheets for 28-pin 3-digit displays: [#1](https://www.lumex.com/spec/LDT-C514RI.pdf), [#2](https://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/BC56-11EWA.pdf) and this seems to be a common pinout. (7 pins for display segments, 1 pin for the dot 1 pin for common-cathode) x 3 digits == 27 pins. So only 1 'spare'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a DMM in Diode mode to find which segment is connected where.

Or, you can check the datasheet. It is a generic part from multiple vendors. [Here](http://wayjun.com/Datasheet/Led/Segment%20Digit%20LED%20Display.pdf) is one option.